# BOSH sessions shares the HTTP connections with other HTTP traffic

Tags: xmpp

The documentation of BOSH mentions that, "Each BOSH session MAY share the HTTP connections with other HTTP traffic ..." . Could anyone explain it a little bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of keep-alive http connections to the XMPP server, the browser may use the connection to access other HTTP services on the XMPP server.